# Trying to implement pointer-events: none in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I have a select dropdown to which I am trying to remove the down arrow using a dummy mask element. But when I click that mask element, the select dropdown is not triggering.

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRGLu/1007/)

If I give `pointer-events: none` to `.slct-drpdwn`, everything works fine but sadly this isn't supported in IE9. So, I thought to implement css `pointer-events: none` like behavior using JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript code which isn't doing anything:

```
var select = document.querySelector('.slct-drpdwn');
select.onclick = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    console.log("in");
    if (!e.preventDefault) { //IE quirks
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Your javascript is working. The problem arises in the fact that you can not "open" a `<select>` element with javascript. You in fact cancel the click event, but this does not help in actually opening the `<select>`. Also changing the `.slct-drpdwn` to be a `<label>` won't help much, as it only highlights the associated element. I guess you should work with a background-image or make the background of the select transparent and let the pseudo pseudo element shine through. At least as a fallback for IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 recognizes pointer events: none, but only for SVG elements. Try this:

```
 <div class="slct">
            <select>
                <option>Foobar</option>
                <option>Bar</option>
                <option>Foo</option>
                <option>Baz</option>
            </select>
            <svg class="slct-drpdwn" id="slct-drpdwn"></svg>
        </div>
        #slct-drpdwn{
                pointer-events: none;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/u8oea7nt/2/

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answers. I think I can go with SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you don't want to use `overflow:hidden;` :
http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/1c7hqddy/1/

```
    .slct {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    border:solid black 1px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div select {
    z-index:1;
    background: transparent;
    border:0;
    width: 200px;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.slct .slct-drpdwn {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
    margin:2px;
    background:red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am actually trying to make my above implementation work in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Try with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/5cbobco5/3/

```
$('.slct-drpdwn').click(function() {
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initMouseEvent('mousedown');
    $('select')[0].dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the closest possible solution. Thanks :)

Comment: The small problem is that the red element is unable to toggle the dropdown functionality. I am trying here to fix it.

Comment: I am assuming you are on Mac. We can see that behaviour on Windows.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something. You can see that behaviour here? http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/sug2wsje/1/

Comment: The above fiddle is working fine on Modern Browsers, on Mac. Before I had checked on windows modern chrome browser where the click on the red element was always opening the dropdown instead of doing a toggle thing. Currently, I can't check on Windows system due to some issues here. I will let you know once I did test on Windows IE9.

Comment: Sorry! If i find other solution, i will tell you.

Comment: Sure Madalina. I will try here too. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this in css, without js:

```
    .slct {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    border:solid black 1px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div select {
    z-index:1;
    width:125%;
    background: transparent;
    border:0;
}
.slct .slct-drpdwn {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
    margin:2px;
    background:red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/fj53g8k9/1/

Comment: You are hiding the down arrow. which will show mismatched select and options' widths. Sorry, I can't do this.

Comment: I understand. It is the best solution that I have now.